# Python threading class for GPIO Led blink

Tags: python, asynchronous, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading, gpio

I come here after after trying in all directions to come out of this problem without any results, unfortunately.

**What I have in mind:**

I need a class, named Led, that in the constructor simply accept a GPIO pin and offer method for:

- Light On
- Light Off
- Blinking

**What I do:**

I have build this class in this way:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread


class Led(Thread):

    def __init__(self, led_pin):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.pin_stop = threading.Event()
        self.__led_pin = led_pin
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.__led_pin, GPIO.OUT)

    def low(self, pin):
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

    def blink(self, time_on=0.050, time_off=1):
        pin = threading.Thread(name='ledblink',target=self.__blink_pin, args=(time_on, time_off, self.pin_stop))
        pin.start()

    def __blink_pin(self, time_on, time_off, pin_stop):
        while not pin_stop.is_set():
            GPIO.output(self.__led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(time_on)
            GPIO.output(self.__led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(time_off)

    def __stop(self):
        self.pin_stop.set()


    def reset(self):
        GPIO.cleanup()

    def off(self):
        self.__stop()

    def on(self):
        self.__stop()
        GPIO.output(self.__led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(self.__led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
```

where the blink method is responsible to indefinitely blink the led until an Off or On method call.

And run this simple code:

```
from classes.leds import Led
import time
from random import randint

Led16 = Led(16)

def main():
    while True:
        if (randint(0, 1) == 1):
            Led16.blink()
        else:
            Led16.off()
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**What happens:**

The Led object seem to spawn a new thread every time that a method is called with the effect that GPIO line become shared between multiple threads.

**What is my wish:**

I want to keep blinking led asynchronous (obviously) and have the control on Led16() object status, maybe without creating new threads each time I cal its method, but at reached this point I am bit confused.

Thank to help me understanding how to reach this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who need this in the future I have do some little adjustment to the proposed code and seem to work fine as expected.

*Again thanks to @barny*

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading

class Led(object):

    LED_OFF = 0
    LED_ON = 1
    LED_FLASHING = 2

    # the short time sleep to use when the led is on or off to ensure the led responds quickly to changes to blinking
    FAST_CYCLE = 0.05

    def __init__(self, led_pin):
        # create the semaphore used to make thread exit
        self.pin_stop = threading.Event()
        # the pin for the LED
        self.__led_pin = led_pin
        # initialise the pin and turn the led off
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.__led_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        # the mode for the led - off/on/flashing
        self.__ledmode = Led.LED_OFF
        # make sure the LED is off (this also initialises the times for the thread)
        self.off()
        # create the thread, keep a reference to it for when we need to exit
        self.__thread = threading.Thread(name='ledblink',target=self.__blink_pin)
        # start the thread
        self.__thread.start()

    def blink(self, time_on=0.050, time_off=1):
        # blinking will start at the next first period
        # because turning the led on now might look funny because we don't know
        # when the next first period will start - the blink routine does all the
        # timing so that will 'just work'
        self.__ledmode = Led.LED_FLASHING
        self.__time_on = time_on
        self.__time_off = time_off

    def off(self):
        self.__ledmode = self.LED_OFF
        # set the cycle times short so changes to ledmode are picked up quickly
        self.__time_on = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        self.__time_off = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        # could turn the LED off immediately, might make for a short flicker on if was blinking

    def on(self):
        self.__ledmode = self.LED_ON
        # set the cycle times short so changes to ledmode are picked up quickly
        self.__time_on = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        self.__time_off = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        # could turn the LED on immediately, might make for a short flicker off if was blinking

    def reset(self):
        # set the semaphore so the thread will exit after sleep has completed
        self.pin_stop.set()
        # wait for the thread to exit
        self.__thread.join()
        # now clean up the GPIO
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I would very much like to be able to use this as it is exactly what I need but the code above gives me errors, I'm not sure if I'm calling it incorrectly. I took Alessandro's code and added led=Led(24) at the end as my call but I get an error that says 'int' object is not callable, I also get an error on __blink_pin - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating lots of threads because your `blink()` creates a new thread every time it is called and the old one isn't stopped.

I suppose there are a couple of options with the thread:

1. Create the thread just once - for example in `__init__()` - and it runs continuously on the blinking time intervals (i.e. sleeping most of the time) reading an instance variable and setting the LED correspondingly. To change the led state, the `blink()`, `on()` and `off()` control the led by setting this instance variable to on/off/blinking.
2. In the blink routine, if the thread is already running either don't create a new thread, or stop the old thread (and wait for it to finish) and then start a new one.

Things you will have to handle are that you want the behaviour to be that:

- If the led is off then the led turns on as soon as `on()` or `blink()` is called
- If the led is blinking and `blink()` is called again the blinking on/off sequence is not disturbed
- If blinking and `off()` is called I would want the on-cycle if it has started to run to completion, i.e. the led should not be turned off immediately because that might be a very short flash which would look odd.

The catch with creating a new thread is waiting for the old one to finish, and it just feels simplest to create the thread just once in `__init__()` and have it running continuously. When the led is on or off, the time period is shortened (to value `FAST_CYCLE`) so that when the led is turned off or on it reacts quickly because the `sleep()` is for a short time.

Some other points about your code:

- I don't think you need to make your class inherit from `Thread` - you are creating a new thread in the `pin=...` line.
- If you add comments as you write the code, usually makes it easier to understand what is going on when reading the code.
- If you keep a reference to the thread (i.e. `self.pin = threading.Thread` not `pin = threading.Thread`) then in the `reset()` you can use `join()` to make sure it has exited before you continue
- As the blink time periods can change and the thread has to use the latest values, use self to read them every time rather than pass them as arguments to the `__blink_pin()` routine, and if doing that you might as well use self to get the pin_stop semaphore too.

---

Something like this (untested):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread

class Led(object):

    LED_OFF = 0
    LED_ON = 1
    LED_FLASHING = 2

    # the short time sleep to use when the led is on or off to ensure the led responds quickly to changes to blinking
    FAST_CYCLE = 0.05

    def __init__(self, led_pin):
        # create the semaphore used to make thread exit
        self.pin_stop = threading.Event()
        # the pin for the LED
        self.__led_pin = led_pin
        # initialise the pin and turn the led off
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.__led_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        # the mode for the led - off/on/flashing
        self.__ledmode = Led.LED_OFF
        # make sure the LED is off (this also initialises the times for the thread)
        self.off()
        # create the thread, keep a reference to it for when we need to exit
        self.__thread = threading.Thread(name='ledblink',target=self.__blink_pin)
        # start the thread
        self.__thread.start()

    def blink(self, time_on=0.050, time_off=1):
        # blinking will start at the next first period
        # because turning the led on now might look funny because we don't know
        # when the next first period will start - the blink routine does all the
        # timing so that will 'just work'
        self.__ledmode = Led.LED_FLASHING
        self.__time_on = time_on
        self.__time_off = time_off

    def off(self):
        self.__ledmode = LED_OFF
        # set the cycle times short so changes to ledmode are picked up quickly
        self.__time_on = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        self.__time_off = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        # could turn the LED off immediately, might make for a short flicker on if was blinking

    def on(self):
        self.__ledmode = LED_ON
        # set the cycle times short so changes to ledmode are picked up quickly
        self.__time_on = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        self.__time_off = Led.FAST_CYCLE
        # could turn the LED on immediately, might make for a short flicker off if was blinking

    def reset(self):
        # set the semaphore so the thread will exit after sleep has completed
        self.pin_stop.set()
        # wait for the thread to exit
        self.__thread.join()
        # now clean up the GPIO
        GPIO.cleanup()

    ############################################################################
    # below here are private methods
    def __turnledon(self, pin):
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)

    def __turnledoff(self, pin):
        GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)

    # this does all the work
    # If blinking, there are two sleeps in each loop
    # if on or off, there is only one sleep to ensure quick response to blink()
    def __blink_pin(self):
        while not self.pin_stop.is_set():
            # the first period is when the LED will be on if blinking
            if self.__ledmode == Led.LED_ON or self.__ledmode == Led.LED_FLASHING: 
                self.__turnledon()
            else:
                self.__turnledoff()
            # this is the first sleep - the 'on' time when blinking
            time.sleep(self.__time_on)
            # only if blinking, turn led off and do a second sleep for the off time
            if self.__ledmode == Led.LED_FLASHING:
                self.__turnledoff()
                # do an extra check that the stop semaphore hasn't been set before the off-time sleep
                if not self.pin_stop.is_set():
                    # this is the second sleep - off time when blinking
                    time.sleep(self.__time_off)
```

Comment: Thank you @barny for the time ant the really well argumented answer.
Tomorrow morning I want to try your proposal for give a feedback to the comunity for a someone future needs.

Comment: If I answered your question, it is customary to accept my answer, and to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will be helpfull, but I came up with that (using `gpiozero`)

```
from gpiozero import LED
import time
import threading

class LEDplus():
    def __init__(self,pinnumber):
        self.led = LED(pinnumber)
        self.__loop = True
        self.__threading = threading.Thread(target=self.__blink)


    def on(self,):
        self.__loop = False
        self.maybejoin()
        self.led.on()

    def off(self, ):
        self.__loop = False
        self.maybejoin()
        self.led.off()

    def maybejoin(self,):
        if self.__threading.isAlive():
            self.__threading.join()

    def blink(self, pitch):
        self.__threading = threading.Thread(target=self.__blink, args=(pitch, ))
        self.__threading.start()

    def __blink(self, pitch=.25):
        self.__loop = True
        while self.__loop:
            self.led.toggle()
            time.sleep(pitch/2)
        self.led.off()

green = LEDplus(18)
green.blink(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [answer of Alessandro Mendolia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959774/10871073), just missing the private methods of the class. Added below with some fixes. The `__turnledon()` does not need an argument - it can access the `self.__led_pin` already stored in initialization.

```
############################################################################
# below here are private methods
def __turnledon(self):
    GPIO.output(self.__led_pin, GPIO.LOW)

def __turnledoff(self):
    GPIO.output(self.__led_pin , GPIO.HIGH)

# this does all the work
# If blinking, there are two sleeps in each loop
# if on or off, there is only one sleep to ensure quick response to blink()
def __blink_pin(self):
    while not self.pin_stop.is_set():
        # the first period is when the LED will be on if blinking
        if self.__ledmode == BlinkerLed.LED_ON or self.__ledmode == BlinkerLed.LED_FLASHING: 
            self.__turnledon()
        else:
            self.__turnledoff()
        # this is the first sleep - the 'on' time when blinking
        time.sleep(self.__time_on)
        # only if blinking, turn led off and do a second sleep for the off time
        if self.__ledmode == BlinkerLed.LED_FLASHING:
            self.__turnledoff()
            # do an extra check that the stop semaphore hasn't been set before the off-time sleep
            if not self.pin_stop.is_set():
                # this is the second sleep - off time when blinking
                time.sleep(self.__time_off)
```